# How can I use Type.GetType() with List'1[UnityEngine.Vector3]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, reflection, gettype

I am currently using:

```
    public static Type FindType(string qualifiedTypeName)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType(qualifiedTypeName);

        if (t != null)
        {
            return t;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                t = asm.GetType(qualifiedTypeName);
                if (t != null)
                    return t;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

kudos to @Alistar from this post : [Type.GetType not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898282/type-gettype-not-working)
However, even this doesnt work when it comes to a list of Vector3s from UnityEngine.
I know that you can include the relevant assembly also by adding ", UnityEngine" at the end, but it doesnt work.

Edit:
Just to clarify, I am trying to use a string value

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.Vector3]"
```

Where the actual list type could be anything, and would like to find the actual Type from this string. This works with regular lists and regular vars, but I get `null` result when it comes to special list types.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You're _never_ going to find a constructed generic type _declared_ in an assembly, i.e. such that the `Assembly.GetType()` method would return the type. That's not how they work. This question is definitely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have some other broader goal that you have mistakenly decided requires reflection to solve. You should post a different question, explaining what that broader goal is, what you've tried so far, and what specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you provide is **not** an [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname)!

It rather looks like it is only the result of [`Type.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.tostring).

e.g. the [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname) of a `List<string>` looks like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

and of a `List<Vector3>` it would be

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```